# Creation of a tensor using a threshold

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I'm working on a neural network taking 32x32 size images as input.
I need to write a custom loss function and I have to create a mask from a size tensor img = (batch, 32, 32) and a size threshold tensor tresh = (batch,).

As each batch has a threshold I would like to be able to create a size tensor (batch, 32, 32) with 0's at places below the threshold and 1's at places above the threshold using only TensorFlow functions.

I've already tried:

```
mask = tf.where(error >= treshold, tf.zeros([batch, 32, 32], tf.float32)+1, tf.zeros([batch, 32, 32], tf.float32))
```

But it doesn't work -do you have a solution?-

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly but you might want to use your threshold as a bias in combination with `relu` activation. tf.where is a non-differentiable function and therefore difficult for learning.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Do you get an error? If so, what is the stack trace? Does the training not work properly? It's difficult to help you without full information

Comment: Sorry, I understand that my question was not clear enough. To put myself in the context I'm working on a variational auto encoder, in input it hangs 32x32x3 images and in output we get a new 32x32x3 image. I then calculate the L2 norm of the difference between these two images, I then get an error tensor of 32x32 size (all between 0 and 1). Then to calculate the loss, my goal is to classify each error into two categories (0 and 1), for this I use Otsu's method to maximize the inter-class variance and to obtain an optimal classification threshold.

Comment: Finally from this classification I calculate my loss function which is in fact the average of the errors classified as 0. So at one point I find myself with a threshold t and an error tensor of size 32x32, my question was to know how to obtain a tensor of size 32x32 with 0 where the error is below the threshold and 1 where the error is above the threshold.

Concerning the training the loss does not decrease I think that this is precisely because I do not use differentiable functions.

Comment: If your want values beyond threshold to be 1 https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid might work. Note that exactly 0 or 1 is not achivable due to the discontinuity of sgn at 0 but sigmoid gets close. Especially if you scale up values and threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
img = tf.random.uniform((100,32,32))
tresh = tf.random.uniform((100,))
tresh_ = tresh[..., tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis] # broadcastable array of thresholds
out = img > tresh_
out = tf.cast(out, dtype=tf.int32)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! However I think that the non-differentiability of the comparison is a problem in the loss function.

Comment: I am 99% sure there should not be any problem with loss function. It is differentiable except for one point. Tensorflow should be able to process it correctly. Please accept the answer if you are happy with it

Comment: Doen't that point crash your backpropagation if you define your loss over it? I'm far from being an expert in Tensorflow. But from a mathematical standpoint it seems difficult for me.

Comment: I am not sure exactly how it works in tensorflow (may be just replacing argument of 0 to something like 0.00001). But comparison is used frequently in models with no problem